# Refreshing parent component from child via event

Tags: lightning-aura-components, refresh

I have yet another event-driven question. How can I send a refresh to a parent component via the child?

*Event*

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" description="CDEContextTagEvent">
    <aura:attribute name="message" type="String" />
</aura:event>
```

*Parent CMP*

```
<aura:handler name="lightningEvent" 
              event="c:CDEContextTagEvent" 
              action="{!c.handleComponentEvent}" />

<aura:attribute name="message" type="String"/>
<p>{!v.message}</p>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.manageView}" var="row">
    <c:CDECContextTagRow view="{!row}"/>
</aura:iteration>
```

*Parent Controller*

```
handleComponentEvent : function(cmp, event, helper){
    var message = event.getParam("message");
    var action = cmp.get("c.CDEContextTagListController");

    action.setCallback(cmp,
        function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === 'SUCCESS'){
                $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
            } else {
                 //do something
            }
        }
    );
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

*Child CMP*

```
<aura:registerEvent name="lightningEvent"
                    type="c:CDEContextTagEvent" />
        <td data-label="">
            <div class="slds-truncate" >
                <button onclick="{!c.callDeleteRecord}" 
                          class="slds-button 
                                 slds-button_icon" 
                          title="Delete Record">
                    <lightning:icon iconName="action:delete" 
                                        size="xx-small" 
                                        alternativeText="Delete"/>
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Delete</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </td>
```

*Child Controller*

```
({
    callDeleteRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var action = component.get("c.deleteTagName");
        var currentRecordId = component.get("v.view.Id");
        action.setParams({"currentRecordId" : currentRecordId});

        var answer = confirm ("Are you sure you want to delete this tag?");
        if(answer){
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams({
                "type": "Error",
                "title": "Deleted!",
                "message": "The deficiency tag has been deleted successfully."
            });
            toastEvent.fire();

            var event = component.getEvent("lightningEvent");
            event.setParams({
                "message" : "MESSAGE TEST" });
            event.fire();
        }
    },
})
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: This all looks correct and you are not using the `message` anywhere in the `handleApplicationEvent` method, and the event is the component type, not the application one, and you used method name `handleApplicationEvent` like you are handling an application type event.

Comment: Oops! Sorry about the naming! Fixed! I am stuck as to why the component isn't refreshing after calling delete. Confirmation alert pops up, toast message pops up, then silent...  :(

Comment: Where are the confirmation alert and the toast message fired? Do you know for sure that your server-side controller is returning successfully?

Comment: @David Hey David, I edited it again to show where exactly it is trying to fire. Also, I'm not able to display the "message" from the parent controller which I'm assuming is due to the event not being fired properly?

Comment: @Jeff What do you mean? Have you inserted some `console.log()` statements in your parent controller's action callback to see what you're receiving (1) in the component event and (2) whether your server controller returns successfully?

Comment: @David I've added some logs on the states of the callbacks for the child and the parent and the parent isn't not logging but the child is and I have the helper call for the function to create the event/setparam/fire right under the line with the log, but doesn't fire . In the parent, the getRecords function is working properly, but I've put an alert and a log inside the parent handleEvent function but it never seems to reach it.